# read a pdf file from url to to byte array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, pdf

In an XML `WebResponse` I get a URL tag which has a link to a PDF file. Example of the URL value is: `https://www.member-data.com/files/hb/c8955fc4d6160ec0fd87f4879c6496d3.pdf`). I have to convert this PDF to a byte array, how do I do this in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`WebClient.DownloadData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx).

Answer (score 26):

You can use `WebClient.DownloadData`, which has a default return value of a byte array. e.g.

```
byte[] bytes = myClient.DownloadData("https://www.member-data.com/files/hb/c8955fc4d6160ec0fd87f4879c6496d3.pdf");
```

Also, this assumes that you want the actual file in a byte array, not the content (text) of the PDF.  That's a whole other ball of wax.

Comment: “which has a default return value of a byte array”. If this one is the default, does that this method has more possible return types?

Comment: Yes I want only contents of a pdf file.

Comment: THis pdf has images and I want those in a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient` is obsolete. Use HttpClient instead:

```cs
string url = "requested/api/url/endpoint"

HttpClient client = new();
client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
```

The GetByteArrayAsync is awaitable, so your method should be an async Task:

```cs
internal async Task<byte[]?> ReadFile()
{
   string url = "requested/api/url/endpoint"

   using HttpClient client = new();
   return client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
}
```

Don't forget to dispose the HttpClient.

Answer (score -2):

To convert a PDF to a byte array use the static method ReadAllBytes in the System.IO namespace

Comment: On what class is this method? If you mean `File.ReadAllBytes()`, then that's not really applicable to downloading from a URL.